# Render general link in Scriban template

Tags: sxa

I am using Sitecore 9.3 and SXA, I need to render the `general link` field in a Scriban template but when I reference it using `i_item.Link` it returns empty.

Is there a specific syntax to render the general link field?

Comment: You are looking for `sc_link` function. Take a look here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html#idm45208463571696_body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this, use custom Scriban extension, see the following code sample:

```
public class GetLinkUrl : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
{
    private readonly IContext context;
    private delegate string LinkUrlDelegate(Item item, string linkFieldName);

    public GetLinkUrl(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var linkTargetUrl = new LinkUrlDelegate(GetLinkURL);
        args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("get_link", (Delegate)linkTargetUrl);
    }

    public string GetLinkURL(Item item, string linkFieldName)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return "#";

        if (item.Fields[linkFieldName] == null)
            return "#";

        LinkField lnkField = (LinkField)item.Fields[linkFieldName];
        if (lnkField == null)
            return "#";

        return lnkField.GetFriendlyUrl();
    }
}
```

And you add the processor above to the generate Scriban context as below:

```
<sitecore>
      <pipelines>
        <generateScribanContext>
          <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.ScribanExtensions.GetLinkUrl, Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" resolve="true" />
        </generateScribanContext>
      </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Now in your Scriban template you can use it as:

```
{{get_link i_item "PromoLink"}}
```

Another way you can control the anchor is to try something like:

```
{{ sc_field i_item "PromoLink" [["attribute1", "attribute1value"],["attribute2", "attribute2value"]]}}
```