# Accessing Link Field Values in a Scriban Template

Tags: sxa, scriban, accessibility

I am using a `Scriban` template in Sitecore 9.3 with SXA and am attempting to render a link field. While the `sc_link` function reliably generates the URL, I cannot seem to find a way to access any other attributes of the *Link Details* such as *Description*, *Alternate Text*, *Style clas*s, *Query strin*g etc.

While I can use the `sc_field` function to pass in attributes to be rendered and it will render the values included in the *Link Details* fields, I cannot append to these values, just over-ride them (and only for the link's attributes).

Using these values from the link selector in Sitecore:

- **Description:** Click Here
- **Target:** New Browser
- **Alternate text:** Alt Title
- **Style class:** my-class
- **Query string:** testing

With this code:

```
sc_field i_item 'CardLink' [['aria-label', (i_item.CardLink.Title.raw)], ['class', 'btn btn-orange'], ['role', 'button']]
```

Results in this markup:

```
<a href="/Company?testing" aria-label="Company" title="Alt Title" role="button" class="btn btn-orange" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Good but there's no way for me to set the `aria-label` to the *Alternate text* value or include a **Font Awesome** icon inside the `<a>` tag.

Outputting the markup directly in the template solves the icon issue, but doesn't seem to give me access to the *Link Details* fields.

This code:

```
<a href="{{ sc_link i_item.CardLink.target }}" class="btn btn-orange" aria-label="{{ i_item.CardLink.Title.raw }}" role="button">
            <ul>
            <li>Description: {{i_item.CardLink.Description}}</li>
            <li>Title: {{i_item.CardLink.Title}}</li>
            <li>Text: {{i_item.CardLink.Text}}</li>
            <li>Class: {{i_item.CardLink.Class}}</li>
            <li>Target: {{i_item.CardLink.Target}}</li>
            <li>URL: {{i_item.CardLink.Url}}</li>
            </ul>
<i class="far fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
```

Results in this markup:

```
<a href="/Company" class="btn btn-orange" aria-label="Company" role="button">
        <ul>
            <li>Description: </li>
            <li>Title: Company</li>
            <li>Text: </li>
            <li>Class: </li>
            <li>Target: /sitecore/content/[Tennant]/[Site]/Home/Company</li>
            <li>URL: /Company</li>
            </ul>  
<i class="far fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
```

Proper URL and easily able to include the icon markup, but no access to the *Link Details* values.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/24106/95 possibly related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you cannot access those properties is because they are not know in the Scriban context provided by the SXA extensions. If you have `i_item.CardLink` in your Scriban template, that will match a `Field` object. This object has some properties (eg Target), but not the properties from a `LinkField`. And those are the ones you are requesting.

There is a solution, but is it not ootb.. and actually there are 2 solutions. Both require custom coding.

**Solution 1: using functions**

You could create a custom function in Scriban for each property you need. Creating custom function is rather easy: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/11/custom-sxa-scriban-extensions.html

It's a quick solution, as the development is easy and you will have quick results. In the easiest form, you might write a function for each property you need but I think there is way to do it passing the required property as a parameter as well (you can pass parameters and you can call properties in C#..).

**Solution2: using a custom object**

Second solution is a bit harder - as you seem to be missing an object for the LinkField you can write that yourself. Adding an object to the Scriban context requires a bit more code: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2020/03/extending-sitecore-scriban-user-object.html.

Benefit of this solution though is that you give access to all the required properties of the LinkField in a proper way. You will still need one function that gets you the LinkField item though (as the ootb Scriban extensions will give you a Field).

Comment: After posting this and reviewing the post referenced here, this seems fair. An object mapping to the LinkField makes the most sense. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 6):

Try using an extension. See https://gist.github.com/auzick/c2e127ed4c6aef0f019eedc0ab738d2b.

```
using Scriban.Runtime;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.Pipelines.GenerateScribanContext;
using System;

namespace Example.ScribanExtensions.Pipelines
{
    public class LinkExtensions : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
    {
        protected readonly IPageMode PageMode;
        private readonly IContext context;
        private delegate LinkInfo LinkInfoDelegate(Item item, object linkFieldName);

        public LinkExtensions(IPageMode pageMode, IContext context)
        {
            PageMode = pageMode;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
        {
            var linkInfo = new LinkInfoDelegate(GetLinkInfo);
            args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_link_info", (Delegate)linkInfo);
        }

        public LinkInfo GetLinkInfo(Item item, object field)
        {
            if (item == null
                || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)field)
                || item.Fields[(string)field] == null
                )
            {
                return null;
            }

            LinkField lnkField = (LinkField)item.Fields[(string)field];
            if (lnkField == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new LinkInfo(lnkField);
        }
    }

    public class LinkInfo
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string anchor { get; set; }
        public string target { get; set; }

        public LinkInfo() { }

        public LinkInfo(LinkField item)
        {
            url = item.GetFriendlyUrl();
            text = item.Text;
            title = item.Title;
            anchor = item.Anchor;
            target = item.Target;
        }
    }

}
```

You wire this up in config like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <generateScribanContext>
                <processor type = "Example.ScribanExtensions.Pipelines.LinkExtensions, Example.ScribanExtensions" resolve="true" />
            </generateScribanContext>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then, access the link properties like this:

```
{{- linkInfo = (sc_link_info i_item 'link') -}}
<ul>
    <li> URL: {{ linkInfo.url}}</li>
    <li> Text: {{ linkInfo.text}}</li>
    <li> Title: {{ linkInfo.title}}</li>
    <li> Anchor: {{ linkInfo.anchor}}</li>
    <li> Target: {{ linkInfo.target}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it works fine but I noticed that the Link field is no longer editable in Sitecore Experience Editor. Is there a way it can be fixed