# Using sc_link_info on Scriban template throwing error

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am new to Sitecore sxa, I have got SXA Scriban template being used in rendering variant. as
/Component-x/default/Link
and this Link has a field where following snippet is provided.

```
{{ if ( o_pagemode.is_experience_editor_editing ) }}
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 10px;">
        <div><b>Title:</b> {{ sc_field i_item 'Title'}}</div>
        <div><b>CssClass:</b> {{ sc_field i_item 'CssClass'}}</div>
        <div><b>Link:</b> {{ sc_field i_item 'Link'}}</div>
    </div>
{{ else }}
    {{ text = i_item.Title }}
    {{ linkInfo = (sc_link_info i_item 'link') }}
    {{ if linkInfo.text != "" }}
    {{ text = linkInfo.text }}
    {{ end }}

    <a href="{{ linkInfo.url }}" alt="{{ text }}" title="{{ text }}" >
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="/img/abcd/xyz.svg#{{ i_item.CssClass }}"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="myClass">{{ text }}</span>
        <i class="icon-indicator"></i> 
    </a>
{{ end }}
```

I am surely missing something here, and am thrown out with following error in just CD, while is ok in experience editor

> /Component/d/Link(9,20) : error : The function `sc_link_info` was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc_link_info` is not out of the box function.

It's a custom extension for Scriban which can be found on github: https://gist.github.com/auzick/c2e127ed4c6aef0f019eedc0ab738d2b

When you open page in Experience Editor, the `else` condition from 7th line of your code is not triggered, so the `sc_link_info` is not used. That's why you don't see exception in Experience Editor, only on CD server.

Here is more info how you can use the extension:

[Accessing Link Field Values in a Scriban Template](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24908/accessing-link-field-values-in-a-scriban-template)